# Law of large number for a product of uniform iid random variables (stick breaking)

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution, law-of-large-numbers

Let $(X_n)_n$, $n = 1, 2, \dots$, be an iid sequence of random variables uniformly distributed on $(0, 1]$. Set $S_0 = 1$ a.s. and, for $n = 1, 2, \dots$, set $S_n = \prod_{k=1}^n X_k$.

Compare $S_n$ and $\mathbb{E} S_n$ for large values of $n$.

---

The hint is to use the Strong Law of Large Numbers.

I thought to use a logarithm transformation to get:
$$
S_n = e^{\log \prod_{k=1}^n X_k} = e^{\sum_{k=1}^n \log X_k} = e^{-n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (-\log X_k)}.
$$

We know that $-\log X_k \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ and $\mathbb{E}[-\log X_k] = 1$, here we can apply SLLN to get:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (-\log X_k) \to 1 \text{ as } n \to +\infty \text{ almost surely.}
$$

Now, is it correct to say this?

$$
S_n = e^{-n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (-\log X_k)} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to +\infty \text{ almost surely.}
$$

And, moreover, is that a solution? I know that $\mathbb{E} S_n = 2^{-n}$ and so $\mathbb{E} S_n \to 0 \text{ as } n \to +\infty$, so they tend to the same limit, but I don't think this will be enough to get a proper comparison between $S_n$ and $\mathbb{E} S_n$. Any sugguestion?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Why? They are uniform on $(0,1)$ so that $S_n$ can be seen as the length of remaining parts of a stick which is being broken step by step and whose original length was $1$.

Comment: You are asked to note that $S_n=e^{-n+o(n)}$ almost surely and that $E(S_n)=2^{-n}$ hence $S_n$ and $E(S_n)$ are not of the same order, actually, $S_n/E(S_n)\to0$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did Oh, thanks! But then, what is that $o(n)$ and where does it come from? I suppose it is related to the SLLN but I can't see the actual relation...

Comment: The SLLN means exactly that $\log\prod\limits_{k=1}^nX_k=nE(\log X_1)+o(n)$ almost surely, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: @Did Great, thank you! Sorry, little o notation still confuses me a bit, but after thinking a bit about what you said is now clear to me. I'll work this way, thank you again!